# What does the Date(0000,00,00) function equal in a SQL environment?

Tags: sql, t-sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am converting a Crystal Report into a SQL query. I have an IF statement in Crystal where

```
if {loanview.FUNDING_DATE} <> Date(0000,00,00)....
```

Is Date(0000,00,00) a current date? Because I see a CurrentDate function as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, I found this following definition of Date(0000,00,00)-

> The special “zero” date '0000-00-00' can be stored and retrieved as
>   '0000-00-00'. When a '0000-00-00' date is used through Connector/ODBC,
>   it is automatically converted to NULL because ODBC cannot handle that
>   kind of date. ... MySQL permits you to store dates where the day or
>   month and day are zero.

To me, it might be a checking which is something like-

```
if {loanview.FUNDING_DATE} <> NULL
BEGIN
    --Place necessary operation when the date is not NULL
END
```

**Note:** This is not a confirmed solution/answer. I just sharing my opinion and you can implement the above logic in SQL and check both part - Report and Query output shows same result or not.